# Не могу создать бинарник с помощью py2exe

Tags: python

Начинаю сборку. Вылазит ошибка

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Documents and Settings\YURIY\Рабочий стол\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
>     setup(windows=["SystemIncefalit.py"])
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
>     raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
> SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
>   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
>    or: setup.py --help-commands
>    or: setup.py cmd --help`
>
> `error: no commands supplied`

Что это?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Comment: И чейта? В командной строке эта строка не работает!

Comment: Поясните что значит не работает? Ничего не происходит после выполнения команды? Или ошибка во время сборки? Или может 'python' не нашелся?